# Is there any way to show both back button and navigation drawer icon together in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I came through a requirment in which we have to show both back button and navigation drawer together. I googled but I only found some apps which are using this like Amazon but still not able to found any way to do.

[image]

Comment: You can use custom `Toolbar` for this instead of `ActionBar`.

Comment: Its ok..But how to do this functionality ..I mean if I will click the back button then it will navigate to back and if I will click hamburger icon then it will open the drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolbar is just a `ViewGroup`, so you can put `ImageButton` inside it, and override it's `ClickListener` to toggle `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any examples

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton

Comment: @Learner glad  to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/openMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Don't forget to remove the programmatically setting of the hamburger icon otherwise you'll have two identical icons.